# Probability of an edge in a random graph

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, sampling

Consider a vertex set $V$ and a degree sequence $(d_v)_{v\in V}$. I want to know **the probability that an edge exists between two given vertices $u$ and $v$ in a random graph with this degree sequence**.

If I am correct, when the graph is built with the [configuration model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model), this probability is:
$$
1 - \left(1 - \frac{d_v}{2m-1}\right)^{d_u}
$$
where $m$ denotes the total number of edges ($m = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{v\in V} d_v$).

Indeed, the wanted probability is one minus the probability that the link does not exist. This probability is the one that each of the $d_u$ stubs of $u$ are not paired with $v$. For each of these stubs, the probability that it is not linked to $v$ is one minus the probability that it is linked to $v$. And this is the probability to choose one of the $d_v$ stubs of $v$ among the $2\cdot m-1$ possible stubs. Right?

When the degrees are not too large, this value is close to $1-\frac{d_u d_v}{2m}$.

BUT the configuration model produces *multi*graphs, and so this is the probability that $u$ and $v$ are linked in a multigraph.

I guess the approximation holds for simple graphs too, because if the degrees are not too large the configuration model produces simple graphs.

But **what about the exact probability?**

Comment: Just checking: By "random graph" you mean "chosen uniformly at random among the labeled graphs that have this degree sequence"?

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 2):

As Jukka writes, exact solutions are unattainable (or uselessly complicated) except for very low degrees and special cases. An example of such a special case is regular graphs of degree $d$, where the probability of an edge is exactly $d/(n-1)$.

The asymptotic probability of an edge as $n\to\infty$ with the degree sequence being a function of $n$ has been solved for a variety of different cases. This is distributed over quite a few papers; I'll mention some.

B. D. McKay, [Asymptotics for symmetric 0-1 matrices with prescribed row sums](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/papers/SymmetricAsympt.pdf), Ars Combinatoria, 19A (1985) 15-26; for the case $d_{max}^4=o(E)$, $E$ being the number of edges.

B. D. McKay, [Subgraphs of dense random graphs with specified degrees](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3018.). Combinatorics, Probability and Computing, 20 (2011) 413-433; for degree approximately linear in $n$ and limited variation of degree.

M. Isaev and B. D. McKay, [Complex martingales and asymptotic enumeration](http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08305). Random Structures and Algorithms, 52 (2018) 617-661; for degree approximately linear in $n$ allowing much greater variation of degree.

A. Liebenau and N. C. Wormald, [Asymptotic enumeration of graphs by degree sequence, and the degree sequence of a random graph](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.08373); this covers the large gap between the first and second papers for when the degrees don't vary too much.

Some other cases like power-law degree sequences have also been done at least partly.
The case of intermediate degree, large variation, is not done except in principle (there is a formula with multidimensional moments and big determinants).

Answer (score 1):

Some observations, that are too long for a comment.

**Obs 1.** The proposed formula for the configuration model cannot be right, because it is not symmetric with respect to $d_u$ and $d_v$.

**Obs 2.** One has to be careful when specifying the "random" graph: what is the intended distribution? If uniform, uniform among what? I don't believe the configuration model generates multigraphs uniformly at random. If we specify three vertices $V=\{1,2,3\}$ and degree sequence $(2,2,2)$, it seems that the configuration model produces

1. with probability $1/15$ the graph with 3 loops
2. with probability $8/15$ the triangle
3. with probability $6/15$ some graph where one vertex has a loop, and the other two vertices have two edges between them. (There are $3$ such multigraphs, so each has probability $2/15$.)
   This is not uniform over the $5$ labelled multigraphs [that have the specified number of vertices and degree sequence], nor over the $3$ possible unlabeled multigraphs.

**Obs 3.** Continuing the case $n=3$ and degree sequence $(2,2,2)$. Take any two vertices, say, 1 and 2. They have degrees $2$ and $2$. The probability that an edge exists between 1 and 2 is:

- $10/15 = 2/3$ in the configuration model ($8/15$ from the triangle, plus $2/15$ from the graph that has one loop at vertex 3).
- $2/5$ if we choose uniformly at random from the $5$ possible multigraphs.
- but the proposed formula, if I understand it right, says $1-(1-2/5)^2 = 16/25$.

For the question on *simple* graphs, chosen uniformly from the graphs that have the required degree sequence, I believe exact formulas may be quite difficult, except in very small cases that can be solved exhaustively.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem raised by Jukka Kohonen comes from the fact that there are several forms of labelling. In [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/16M1087175) by Fosdick et al. the authors make an interesting distinction between stub-labeled multigraphs and vertex-labeled multigraphs.

Usually people imply vertex-labeled multigraphs, as is the case of Jukka when asserting "I don't believe the configuration model generates multigraphs uniformly at random.". The configuration model produces uniformly at random stub-labeled (loopy) multigraphs, as discussed in the section 3 of the reference above (where I think it is described as Bollobas stub-matching method). In the example of the (2,2,2) sequence, the 15 graphs mentioned are different stub-labeled multigraphs.

Note also that a vertex-labeled graph is isomorphic to $ \prod _i d_i ! $ stub-labeled graphs, which may be useful to go from one enumeration to the other.

In anyway, I agree that the probability proposed in the original question is not correct in the context of the configuration model.